# Thyme, Spring: stuck on creating a single item view

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have successfully implemented adding a visit and showing a list of all visits, but now I'm stuck on creating a view for a single visit.

My findById function works:

```
logger.info("Visit id 2 -> {}", repository.findById(2));

Visit id 2 -> DentistVisitDTO[id='0', dentistName='Mait Kuusevaik', visitTime='2018-10-12T12:15']
```

And when I click on a list item it sucessfully redirects to a url using ID (i.e "/results/1" and so on. Is there a way I can use the ID from the URL and somehow render the item on the page using findById()?

I'm new to Spring and Thyme.

```
public DentistVisitDTO findById(long id) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM DENTIST_VISIT where id=?", new Object[] { id },
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<DentistVisitDTO>(DentistVisitDTO.class));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **@RequestMapping** annotation of SpringMVC/SpringWeb to get the id attribute from the URL:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RequestMapping(value="/results/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String detail(@PathVariable(value="id") String id, Model model) {
    DentistVisitDTO dentistVisit = repository.findById(id);
    System.out.println("GET /results [" + id + "]");
    model.addAttribute("dentistVisit", dentistVisit);
    return "details";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Had to change "String id" to "long id" otherwise perfect!